# angularjs directive, jquery class selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular directive that displays a treeview.  When you click on the li icons it is supposed to hide the nested ULs.

Here's the code that matters: (this is in a click function where e is the click event)

```
$toggler=$(e.target).closest('li');
if($toggler.hasClass("collapsed")){
 $toggler.removeClass("collapsed").addClass("expanded");
} else {
  $toggler.removeClass("expanded").addClass("collapsed");
}
$(".collapsed").find("ul").hide();
$(".expanded").find("ul").show();
```

I can see in the debugger that the class is being assigned and removed properly.  However, it only works for the first set of LIs where I initially set the class as collapsed.  The deeper levels of the tree are showing the class changes but the selector doesn't work with them. Interestingly, when you click on a deeper row it acts like you're clicking the root row the first time. after that it does nothing.

The question: Why isn't my selector working?

here's my plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/GZ5MZjkir4AaNQmHIxFP?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you first apply `.collapsed` and then `.expanded`. So your children are always expanded if the root is expanded. If you swap them, it works like intended:

```
$(".expanded").find("ul").show();
$(".collapsed").find("ul").hide();
```

So it first expands all the children. Then it reaches the first `.collapsed` child, collapses it. After this continues collapsing `.collapsed` children bringing no visual difference.

Comment: ah I see, find returns any child, grand child etc. down the chain, not just the direct descendents.  that works!